# vector as production of matrices, trouble with exp()

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

A vector $(a_{11}x, a_{22}y, a_{33}z)$ can be expended as:

$$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11}x \\ a_{22}y\\  a_{33}z
\end{pmatrix} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
   a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
   a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}\odot
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0\\
  0& 1 &0\\
  0&0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
\\&=
\begin{pmatrix}
  * & * \\
  * & * \\
  * & * 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  * & * & *\\
  * & * & *
\end{pmatrix}\odot
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0\\
  0& 1 &0\\
  0&0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

but how can I write the following vector as product of matrices:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  exp(a_{11})x \\ exp(a_{22})y\\  exp(a_{33})z
\end{pmatrix}$$
the annoying exp() prevents me doing any transformation!
Maybe the question is: is there a exp() function whose parameter is a vector instead of a single number?

Comment: Actually your expansion of the original matrix should be $$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&0&0\\0&a_{22}&0\\0&0&a_{33}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: Of course you can define yourself a function that applies the exponential to each of the components of a vector, but it would interact quite badly with the linear structure of matrix algebra. (It wouldn't be a linear transformation, or even close to it). What exactly are you trying to do, and are you sure linear algebra is the right tool for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your original question has changed significantly. If $$A=\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{a}_{11}} & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & {{a}_{22}} & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & {{a}_{33}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$
then $$\exp (A)\left( \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
   z  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   \exp ({{a}_{11}}) & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & \exp ({{a}_{22}}) & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & \exp ({{a}_{33}})  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
   z  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   \exp ({{a}_{11}})x  \\
   \exp ({{a}_{22}})y  \\
   \exp ({{a}_{33}})z  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$
This is quite different from your original post which required $$\left( \begin{matrix}
   \exp ({{a}_{11}}x)  \\
   \exp ({{a}_{22}}y)  \\
   \exp ({{a}_{33}}z)  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$

Comment: Many thanks! Matrix exponential saves me!